# How can i properly change the keys name in my dict?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, dictionary

trying to change my dictionary keys name using this code :

```
for key in my_dict_other:
    new_key = key + '/' + str(my_dict[key])
    # new_key = key + '/' + str(my_dict[key][0][0]) + '-' + str(my_dict[key][0][1])
    my_dict_other[new_key] = my_dict_other.pop(key)
```

however one of the keys is getting out like this `"9-9/[['2550', '1651']]/[]"` instead of this `"9-9/[['2550', '1651']]"` how can i fix it and ideally adjust my code to have them get out like this `"9-9/2550-1651"` for that purpose i tried this `new_key = key + '/' + str(my_dict[key][0][0]) + '-' + str(my_dict[key][0][1])` but i get list out of range at some point .

**Edit:** How can i make a regex that would remove all occurrences of `'/[]'` for example the output of  `39-10/[['5400', '3601']]/[]/[]` should be `39-10/[['5400', '3601']]`

Comment: That sounds like a heavily layered XY problem. I don't think that using the string representation of a list as part of a dictionary key is the way to go. Can you show more context of what you are **actually** trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
import re

key = "9-9/[['2550', '1651']]/[]"
newkey = re.sub("[\[\]']", "", key.replace("/[]", ""))

# '9-9/2550, 1651'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your examples correctly, you can use a dictionary comprehension instead of regex:

```
my_dict = {k.replace("/[]", ""): v for k, v in my_dict.items()}
```